# Conflicting Namespace Resolution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, namespaces

I am using a library called [BCrypt.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt-Official/), the author made the Namespace the same name as the Class, so the Class full path is: BCrypt.Net.BCrypt, where BCrypt.Net is the Namespace and BCrypt is the Class name.

I am trying to use in my code, like all the examples I can find use, like:

```
BCrypt.HashPassword("234");
```

But Visual Studio complains saying:

> Error 3   The type or namespace name 'HashPassword' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'BCrypt' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

I have the assembly in my project (since I got it from NuGet):

[image: Assembly Reference]

If I add a `using BCrypt.Net;` or `using BCrypt;`, before my namespace the error says the same.
I I add it inside my namespace, something funny happens. I works, the code compiles and executes. BUT Visual Studio shows an error! I can't understand how it compiles with an error.

```
namespace Test.Data
{
    using BCrypt.Net; // The 'Net' is marked with a Red Error line in VS2013
    ....
    string s = BCrypt.HashPassword("234");
```

> Error 3   The type name 'Net' does not exist in the type >'BCrypt.Net.BCrypt'

The error (but compiles and executes fine) is the same for `using BCrypt = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt;`

So what's going on?

---

Edit:

I know I can use it as `BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword("234");`, but I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can solve this issue adding an alias to the namespace. Something like this:

```
using BCr = BCrypt.Net;

namespace Program {

   public class MyClass {

     public void MyMethod() {
        var s = BCr.BCrypt.HashPassword("234");
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. See at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx to understand why they shouldn't use the same name to both class and namespace.

Comment: I saw @sprinter252 's answer and it works as well. In that case you should define an alias to a type instead of a namespace.

Comment: For me, just using `using BCrypt.Net;` inside the namespace works, but `Net` is shown as an error by VS2013 and all the other options that work show it as well.

Comment: I created a project on VS2013 Ultimate using the library and it has worked fine. When I add `using BCrypt.Net;` inside the namespace no error is shown. Even with @sprint252 suggestion works fine. Maybe VS installation issue?

Comment: hmmm maybe, I have it inside a Class Library project btw

Comment: @MAC The link to the Eric Lippert blog in your first comment is dead now.  I'm not yet able to edit it, but it's now available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190124234212/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/).

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
using BCrypt = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt;
```

to your usings:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    using BCrypt = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BCrypt.HashPassword("234");
        }
    }
```

Proofing screen:

[image: VS 2015 likes this]

Comment: Works the same as `using BCrypt.Net;` inside the namespace, VS2013 shows the same error, compiles ok, executes ok.

Comment: mFeinstein I added a screenshot that shows my studio. Compile and run is ok too.

Comment: try just `using BCrypt.Net;` instead of the alias, see if your VS shows any errors. I am in VS2013, which is yours?

Comment: I use VS 2015 Enterprise